# Create PayPal Recurring Profile with credit card

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I am trying to implement **PayPal recurring profile with credit card** with sandbox following is request array 
Array ( [METHOD] => CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile [VERSION] => 64 [PWD] => GF9FVNGTX8Q26NUS [USER] => seller.snehal_api1.webwingtechnologiees.com [SIGNATURE] => AZW4jy5VDSJ42-DKw.lf6YCXJPwgA9AudMP0iOJAtgitCntJzXkVv0dd [AMT] => 5.00 [CURRENCYCODE] => USD [PAYMENTACTION] => Sale [CREDITCARDTYPE] => Visa [ACCT] => 4658195337958982 [EXPDATE] => 122014 [CVV2] => 962 [FIRSTNAME] => sachin [LASTNAME] => n [PROFILESTARTDATE] => 2014-02-26 [DESC] => test profile [BILLINGPERIOD] => Day [BILLINGFREQUENCY] => 1 )

But getting following error 
Array ( [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-02-26T07:28:36Z [CORRELATIONID] => 3f38a9a538320 [ACK] => Failure [VERSION] => 64 [BUILD] => 9777850 [L_ERRORCODE0] => 11586 [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => DPRP is disabled. [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => DPRP is disabled for this merchant. [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error )

Any one can please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your account is not set up for Direct Card Recurring Payments. Shoot us a ticket at https://www.paypal.com/mts and we'll get you set up. Thanks!